# what public service project would you create 

Tags: projects

if you had

- 4 software developers
- any open source software
- server hardware
- internet connection for hosting
- 100 person days in which to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a site equivalent to Rent-a-Coder but for non-profits to solicit volunteer or low-cost developers for public service projects (i.e. make your question easy for the next guy in an equivalent situation).  Given the current economic troubles, there are likely to be both a lot of unemployed developers and a lot of troubled non-profits (and a lot of demand for the various kinds of help those non-profits provide).  Let's put them together.

Add a point system like StackOverflow so you can earn points by helping out non-profits with their web applications or whatever.  Then go get some corporate sponsorship so that you can turn your points into credits at Amazon.com or some such.

Answer (score 0):

Something to replace [diebold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_Election_Solutions#Security_issues) software?

Duke Nukem Forever? :P

Comment: If you think you can develop a secure voting system in 800 man hours you are HIIIIIIGH.  Nice sentiment, but totally high.

Comment: That's how they did it originally, isn't it?